# correct python google ads library?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-ad-manager, google-ads-api

Tasked with writing a client to interact with Google Ad Manager.  From what I can tell there are three "official" python client libraries on PyPi released by Google.  One seems to be legacy, as indicated in its README, but the other two seem to be actively developed.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client   (Legacy, first release = 2011)

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib  (first release = 2014)

https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python  (first release = 2018)

The latter two have the same three developers.  Which to use?

Answer (score 8):

Per David Wihl on GitHub, the correct answer is google-ads-python:

https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/issues/258#issuecomment-611126627